# Can you remove "days" from "came just days after"?

Tags: phrase-usage, time, parts-of-speech

> The announcement late on Monday came just days after Ma's online shopping giant Alibaba was hit with a record $2.8 billion antitrust fine.

In the above sentence, can "days after" could be replaced with "after"? If it can't be replaced, what component is "day" functioning as?

Comment: It could be removed, but would add ambiguity. "just after" could mean minutes after, seconds after, or months after.

Comment: Okey, but I have another question，Why can we add a noun before an adverbial clause，“before......”. or I can think the days as a noun that was brought to ahead

Comment: If something happens "a few days after the event" and you (the writer) consider that a short period of time between the two events, you can add "just" or "only" to indicate that: "just a few days after". And that phrase can be shortened to "just days after".

Comment: Well, you could say "several 24-hour periods after".

Comment: If you removed "days" from that, personally I would think it meant within hours of it.